# what is the difference between either and Option in dartz?

Tags: flutter, dart, dartz

i am trying to understand dartz, but the documentation is not clear enough.
i need to get the  difference between either and Option in dartz?

```
abstract class Option<A> implements TraversableMonadPlusOps<Option, A>
```

**VS**

```
abstract class Either<L, R> implements TraversableMonadOps<Either<L, dynamic>, R>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, an [`Option`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) type normally is a type that holds either a typed value, or nothing.

For example if you want to get the first integer of a list of integers, that might be an `Option<int>` because it can be an int or *nothing* in case the list is empty. But it cannot be a string.

An `Either` type is just what the name says... either one or the other. And it can be two different types altogether. `Either<int, string>` would have either an int *or* a string. Never both. Never none. Either one or the other.

For example a functional ParseInt method might return a `Either<int, string>`, because it will return either a valid int, or an error message.